# How do I get a subquery to be updated for each row inserted in mysql?

Tags: mysql, insert, max, subquery

My query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (lfd, somedata)
select (select max(lfd) + 1 from table1), somedata from table2
```

Table2 has multiple rows. So I want multiple rows inserted into table1.
That works, but lfd is set to the same number for all inserted rows.

So if max(ldf) + 1 is "2" for the first row inserted, it's "2" for all the following rows too. That's incorrect, because max(lfd)  + 1 for the next row should return "3" of course.

How do I tell mysql to reevaluate the subquery for each insert?

I can't touch the table structures because I migrate data from one php-gallery into a second different php-gallery. The structure of the tables is under the control of the applications.

In Oracle I would simply define a sequence and select the squeencename.nextval in the subselect. - I am pretty sure that would work, but mysql does not offer sequences as far as I know, right?

Comment: same as the answer, same problem: i can't touch the table sctructure.

Comment: You could face concurrency issues doing this any other way (unless you lock the table) - is there the possibility that other users/connections might also be inserting new records into `table1` table whilst your query is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once:

```
SELECT MAX(lfd) + 1 INTO @i FROM table1;

INSERT INTO table1 (lfd,col1,...)
SELECT @i:=@i+1,somedata,... FROM SomeTable;
```

Essentially this would just use a variable as a sequence, initializing it with the current maximum id from the table.

Note that you might have concurrency issues here if rows are inserted into `table1` while this query is running.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Just define `lfd` to be an [autoincrement column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html).  Then you won't have to bother with `select max(...) ...`.</s>

Here's a different way to do it:

```
insert into table1 (lfd, somedata)
select 
  (
    select count(*) + (select count(*) from table1) 
    from table2 l
    where l.lfd <= r.lfd
  ),
  r.somedata
from table2 r;
```

How this works:

1. ranks the rows in `table2` from 1 to n (where n is the number of rows in `table2`)
2. adds the initial `max(lfd)` to the ranks so the values will be unique

Caveats:  this is an n**2 query, so if you have a big data set this could take a while.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sadly I can't touch the table structures because I migrate data from one php-gallery into a second different php-gallery. The structure of the tables is under the control of the applications.

Comment: @MattFenwick: My bad, I thought the `select .. from table1` subquery would fluff it up.  What about concurrency issues though, if other concurrent inserts are taking place into `table1`?  Might result in collisions...